# Overloading operator < relational C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have tried to answer this question but I could not.Can you help me.Vector3Ds is class which takes in 3d mathematical vector like x,y,z in an array:

question:
Suppose that you want to be able to store Vector3Ds inside an STL set. You delegate this task to a friend who returns with the following implementation of operator <:

```
 bool Vector3D::operator< (const Vector3D& other) const
{
for(int k = 0; k < NUM_COORDINATES; ++k)
if(coordinates[k] < other.coordinates[k]) return true;
return false;
}
```

This implementation of operator < will cause serious problems if Vector3Ds are stored in an STL set or map. Why is this? (Hint: What are the mathematical properties of the less-than operator, and do
they all apply to this implementation?).I tried the above code and it seems ok.no error and elements are sorted in order.why the question says it will cause serious problem.

```
Vector3D.h

class Vector3D
{
public:

Vector3D();

void set(int arrayIndex,int num);

bool operator< (const Vector3D& other) const;

private:

static const int NUM_COORDINATES = 3;
double coordinates[NUM_COORDINATES];
};



Vector3D.cpp

#include "Vector3D.h"

Vector3D::Vector3D(void){

}


 void Vector3D::set(int arrayIndex,int num){

coordinates[arrayIndex]=num;



}
 bool Vector3D::operator< (const Vector3D& other) const
 {
for(int k = 0; k < NUM_COORDINATES; ++k)
if(coordinates[k] < other.coordinates[k]) return true;
return false;
 }
```

Comment: If you tested the code and didn’t encounter problems, your test wasn’t very good. You’ll need to insert values for which the conditions for a strict weak irder don’t hold according to your definition of `operator<`. Which values will cause problems exactly will depend on the classes/functions you use your objects with.

Comment: Calculate the length of the vector and use that in your comparison, rather than comparing coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `operator<` does not meet the needs of [strictly weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) requirement.

Let's take two points:

p1 = [1, 2, 0] and
p2 = [2, 1, 0].

Per your implementation, p1 < p2 **and** p2 < p1. That is going to be a problem when ordering of objects.

One solution is to use:

```
bool Vector3D::operator<(const Vector3D& other) const
{
   for(int k = 0; k < NUM_COORDINATES; ++k)
   {
      if(coordinates[k] != other.coordinates[k])
      {
         return (coordinates[k] < other.coordinates[k]);
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I knew this bit if(coordinates[k] != other.coordinates[k]) was missing in the question code.

Comment: But why there was no error when i used my above code which is with out if(coordinates[k] != other.coordinates[k]).

Comment: @TikaGurung, with that check, p1 < p2 is true and p2 < p1 is false.

Comment: can you clarify more mate.Im still confused.

Comment: @TikaGurung, Create two objects. `Vector3D p1, p2;`. Set their coordinates to [1, 2, 0] and [2, 1, 0], respectively. Now, use `std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p1 < p2) << " " << (p2 < p2) << std::endl;`. Try that with your original function and then with my suggestion. Does the output make sense? Does that help you understand why your implementation is a problem and why my suggestion is not a problem?

Comment: yes the output make sense.How come p1 [1,2,0] is less than p2 [2,1,0]? is it because 1 is less than 2?

Comment: is it right it only compare the first element of the array ? coz second element of p1 is greater than p2.

Comment: yes apparently it only compares the first element as i checked with different numbers.

Comment: @TikaGurung, that won't be correct. In that case, points [2,1, 0] and [2, 2, 0] will be considered to be equal. I don't think you want that.

Comment: Thank you man I am playing with the code using debugger and its making more sense now.